# Hide show in JavaScript using classes instead of ids

Tags: javascript, show-hide, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have seen previous questions about trying to use classes instead of ids for hide show in JavaScript.  However, I haven't really found any definitive answers.  I need to use a class because I have an FAQ section where I am inputting questions and hide / showing the answers.  Here's my code using ids:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
        var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
            text.innerHTML = text() + " show";
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            text.innerHTML = text() + " hide";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

How do I change this JavaScript to use classes?  I tried changing getElementById to getElementByClassName, but I don't know why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a conceptual difference between [classes and IDs](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). Classes are not unique, so you will not be able to retrieve a single element when querying for a class. You can surely get a list with a single element, but it will still be a list because you can possibly have more than one element with the same class. On the other hand, IDs are unique, and this is why you can select a direct element by using a method to get it by its ID.

The correct JavaScript method for retrieving objects by their class is `getElementsByClassName` (note that by the `s` it will return a **list** of elements, and not a single result as you probably expected).

You have to parse the returned list to get the element(s) you want.

Just to illustrate, you can toggle the `display` attribute of the first returned element by doing:

```
var displayedTexts = document.getElementsByClassName("displayText");
displayedTexts[0].style.display = "none";
```

You can see a JS Fiddle with a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e01vu2wa/).